# unable to read cookie first time in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies

I am using Javascript to set the cookie and read the value from cookie.I am using the code available at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp for creating and reading the value of cookie.when the page loads i am checking that whether that cookie exists or not .Every thing is working fine except it is not reading the cookie when i set it first time and try to read in next page load .it is setting the cookie but does not read only first time .

Here is my code :-

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

//To get the cookie:-
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
//to Delete the cookie:-
function cookieDelete(c_name) {
    setCookie(c_name, "delete", -1);
}
```

And on page load i am using it like :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       var aZ = getCookie("menuSave");
       if (aZ) {
           //do Some thing here 
       }
       else {
           setCookie("menuSave", "mysp", null);

       }


   });
```

Comment: Please show us your exact javascript code.  That's the only way we can see what the problem is with YOUR code.

Comment: @jfriend00:- I have updated my question with code .

Comment: @Pranav Don't use w3schools.com as a reference (see [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com)), better rely on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: Do you have any cookie viewer on your browser (or developer tools if you use mozilla?). It's a long guess but since you haven't setup a path and a domain, it creates different cookies (depending on your page path).

Comment: @Andreas:- +1 for you . since i was using W3school's code as reference and i was not setting the path. the whole problem was due to that. MDN is good for learning i totally agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a 'path' to your cookie. For example:

```
document.cookie = 'ppkcookie2=yet another test; expires=Fri, 27 Jul 2001 02:47:11 UTC; path=/';
```

The path represents the relative path in your website which the cookie will be readable.

`path=/` means it'll be readable on your whole website.
`path=/common/` means it'll be readable only in /common/ folder (and its subfolders)

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the answer to your problem but yet a alternative easier solution, hope it helps!

save menu

```
localStorage.setItem("menusave","vale");
```

load value

```
localStorage.getItem("menusave");
```

Just trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have marked the question as asp.net,

You can set the cookies as follows:

```
HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("lastVisit");
aCookie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

And read it back like:

```
if(Request.Cookies["lastVisit"] != null)
    Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["lastVisit"].Value);
```

Refer [MSDN Cookies overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `null` for the expiration days it makes your cookie into a session cookie that will not persist very long.

Change this:

```
setCookie("menuSave", "mysp", null);
```

to this to give it an actual expiration date:

```
setCookie("menuSave", "mysp", 7);
```

If you want to retrieve the cookie from any page besides the exact same page that set it, you will also need to set a path value in the cookie that allows the cookie to be retrieved on more than just the exact page that set it.

Comment: thanks a lot .. it was just missing the path.voted up for your helpful answer.